# Discord.py проблема с БД

Tags: python

пишу функцию создания временных комнат, столкнулся с проблемой ID
для того чтобы функция работала, нужно задать переменную с ID комнаты и категории в гильдии
мне нужно что бы эта переменная брала данные из базы данных(использую sqlite3).
Вот код:

```
def getChID(ctx, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild
    GuildName = guild
    name = guild.id
    dbo = sqlite3.connect("Discord.db")
    db = dbo.cursor() 
    db.execute(f"SELECT VoiceChannelID FROM `{name}` where GuildName=`{GuildName}`")

def getCatID(ctx, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild
    GuildName = guild
    name = guild.id
    dbo = sqlite3.connect("Discord.db")
    db = dbo.cursor() 
    db.execute(f"SELECT categoryID FROM `{name}` where GuildName=`{GuildName}` ")    

#создание приватной комнаты
default_rooms_initted = False
default_room_category_id = getCatID(guild)
default_room_creator_id = getChID(guild)
```

ошибка:

```
File "c:/Users/mrlud/DSbot/NBot/bot.py", line 192, in <module>
   default_room_category_id = getCatID(Guild)
 File "c:/Users/mrlud/DSbot/NBot/bot.py", line 182, in getCatID
   guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild
AttributeError: type object 'Guild' has no attribute 'guild'
```

Перевод примерно такой:
тип объекта Guild не имеет аттрибута guild

Comment: `default_room_category_id = getCatID(guild)` - а `ctx` где передаётся?

Comment: думаю не требуется писать ctx аргументом в этой строке, ведь  я использую функцию getCatID, в которой уже есть ctx